# why is c++'s metaprogramming not added into its native feature?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm getting really interested in c++ after it's c++ 11 TR and I'm expecting for c++1y.
I wonder why c++'s metaprogramming is not added into its native feature.
(We know that D language has static if and D is heavily using it) (I don't know much about D lang. I just heard about it.)

C++'s metaprogramming is used for years, saying at least 8-10 years.
However, metaprogramming can lead to messy code.
Boost has MPL, but it's not strong enough as D lang.

I'm a newbie college student and I can't comment on the standard. I'm just wondering is there someone telling the committee that at least some amount of people need this feature??

Maybe take a look at Metatrace, using a lot of metaprogramming (Metatrace is a C++ compile time ray tracer):
https://github.com/phresnel/metatrace

Comment: "*it's c++ 11 TR*" There is no such thing as a "C++11 TR". C++11 is a standard, not a technical report. Also, metaprogramming is about a *lot* more than just `static if`.

Comment: It's slowly evolving there. Things are definitely improving: `auto`, `decltype`, `declval`, variadic templates, `type_traits` inside the stdlib, many more legal uses of (local) templates and/or default arguments: it's getting more polished, without trying to create a new language

Comment: One of the benefits of c++ is that it provides tools to create higher level abstractions _without_ enforcing what those abstractions may be. Over time useful abstractions that are in common use have library and (if absolutely necessary) language features added to ease their use; e.g. `auto` et.al pointed out be @sehe above

Answer (score 2):

There are numerous proposals being considered to add additional metaprogramming facilities to the language.  "Static if" is one such feature being considered; two papers that propose variations of this are [N3322](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3322.pdf) and [N3329](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3329.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

Remember, C++'s template meta-programming was mostly discovered by accident. They didn't design it with turing-completeness in mind, it just sort of happened. That's the main reason why meta-programming facilities aren't baked more into the language proper.

With regards to static if, I believe that's been proposed for a later standard (edit: see the other response for the proposal papers). C++ is slowly adopting more features for meta-programming as it evolves (see constexpr) and we'll hopefully see more in due time.